# KDE for Ubuntu question

Tags: kde

I just tried to install KDE for Ubuntu 16.04 using the recommended package: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`, but I got an error when installing:

```
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now it won't let me remove what it install asking me to run `apt-get -f install` without packages first, but when I run it, I get the same error above.

Any ideas what I can do to either install KDE or remove kubuntu-desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the software centre and see if it would not let me remove and or install the same package again.
Reboot your system before to stop all the processes that might run in the background
Add a comment to reply.

Comment: I tried, but it did not let me remove it, I ended up re-installing Ubuntu.

Comment: That is an simmilar thing that happened to me i also have a fresh install of ubuntu on my pc now just three days old